# Verifying sum of sequence under a condition in dafny

Tags: verification, dafny

I am having a problem with getting an invariant to be be maintained in dafny. The invariant is trying to maintain that a total is equal to the a recursive sum of elements in a sequence that match a given condition. What do i need to add/change to get this to verify. Here is my attempt:

```
datatype MovieTitle = A | B | C

class Movie {
  var title: MovieTitle;
  var run_time: int;

  predicate Valid()
  reads this
  {
      run_time >= 0
  }

  constructor(mt: MovieTitle, rt: int)
  requires rt >= 0;
  ensures Valid();
  modifies this;
  {
      title := mt;
      run_time := rt;
  }
}

function movieSum(s: seq<Movie>, mt: MovieTitle, i: int): int
requires 0 <= i <= |s|;
decreases s, i;
reads s;
reads set x | x in s[..];
{
  if |s| == 0 || i == 0 then 0
  else if s[0].title == mt then s[0].run_time + movieSum(s[1..], mt, i - 1)
  else movieSum(s[1..], mt, i - 1)
}

lemma {:induction s, mt, i} movieSumLemma(s: seq<Movie>, mt: MovieTitle, i: int)
requires 0 <= i < |s|;
ensures s[i].title == mt ==> (movieSum(s, mt, i) + s[i].run_time == movieSum(s, mt, i + 1)) &&
  s[i].title != mt ==> (movieSum(s, mt, i) == movieSum(s, mt, i + 1));
decreases s;
{

}

method SumRuntimes(s: seq<Movie>)
{
  var total := 0;
  var i := 0;

  while i < |s|
  invariant 0 <= i <= |s|;
  invariant total == movieSum(s, A, i);
  decreases |s| - i;
  {
    if s[i].title == A {
      total := total + s[i].run_time;
      movieSumLemma(s, A, i);
    }

    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

Here `invariant total == movieSum(s, A, i);` won't hold. Any help in getting this to verify is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function `movieSum`. You're both chopping off the initial element of `s` in the recursive call and decrementing `i`. That will not produce the sum of all the `mt`-movie elements.

You don't need the lemma. But its postcondition doesn't say what you may think it says. It currently has the form

```
ensures A ==> B && !A ==> C
```

The 2-character-wide `&&` has higher binding power than the 3-character-wide `==>`. So, your postcondition is saying

```
ensures A ==> ((B && !A) ==> C)
```

which simplifies to `true`. Instead, you want

```
ensures (A ==> B) && (!A ==> C)
```

which you can also write on two lines (for better readability):

```
ensures A ==> B
ensures !A ==> C
```

Your program also has a number of redundant `decreases` clauses and `:induction` attributes. I'm guessing you have added these from the blue information squiggles in the IDE. The blue squiggles are just FYI--Dafny is just trying to tell you what its default settings are.

It seems you may be using a very version of Dafny, or I expected you should have got a warning about the deprecated `modifies this` on the constructor.